# How to write a contains statement to match a member of a class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, conditional-statements, contains

If I have the following structure:

```
Public Class UserData
    Public ID As String
    Public Name As String
End Class
```

How can I select it in a conditional like this?

```
Dim myUsers As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UserData)

If myUsers.Contains(.ID = "1") = True Then
    ...
```

I know that `myUsers.Contains(.ID = "1")` is totally wrong, but I am curious how to do something like that?  Is it possible?  Is this a job for LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
If myUsers.Any(Function(u) u.ID = "1") Then
   ...
```

Of course, if you're going to do this more than once, you'll probably be better off creating a set to search in:

```
Dim myUserSet = New HashSet(Of String)(myUsers.[Select](Function(u) u.ID))
For Each userId In selectedUserIds
    If myUserSet.Contains(userId) Then
       ...
```

*My vb is rusty. Please forgive syntax errors*

Comment: I will be doing this more than once, but it is in a `RowDataBound` event... so any type of optimization like that would just be run over and over again... unless I used a static member?  I'm pretty new to .NET

Comment: @afuzzyllama: You should be able to create the HashSet in the same scope as myUsers. If myUsers is calculated based on data within your event, then there's probably no point creating a HashSet.

Comment: `I am getting this: 'Any' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UserData)`.  I will try the HashSet idea though.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: "Any" is an extension method. You'll need to include the `System.Linq` namespace in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the VB version:

```
If myUsers.Any(Function(i) i.ID = "1") Then ...
```

Comment: I am getting this: `'Any' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UserData)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Dictionary

```
var myUserDict = new Dictionary<String, UserData>
if(myUserDict.ContainsKey("1"))..
```

Makes only sense of course if you are going to do anything with the selected user.

Comment: To your 'Any' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UserData) problem: Are you using the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: No... No I am not.  I am assuming this is why I don't see the `Any()` function.  Also, I am doing it in the fashion I am because I am binding the data to a GridView